# Jquery Drag and Drop to create menu (similar to wordpress custom menus)

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I want to create a similar effect to the one in the custom menu in `wordpress 3.0+`
What i want:

I want to be able to create a custom menu via drag and drop (with or without sub elements)
I need to have all my pages in a list and be able to add them and order them via drag and drop

I found: http://papermashup.com/drag-drop-with-php-jquery/  a great sorting via drag and drop tutorial(with files included) but it does not allow me to add new elements or remove any of them.

I found a little more and i found: http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/shopping-cart-php-jquery/ but again this one lets me add and remove items but does not let me sort them the way i need.

Once added, the element should be removed from the list and show only in the menu.

I was wandering if anyone can point me into the right direction, or help in any way, or maybe someone already did this kind of thing or has an idea of how it should be.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for something similar myself. That's what lead me to this question. And, I don't know if you're still looking for a solution, but perhaps someone is or will.

There is a project on GitHub that provides for reordering of items:
[laravel-shop-menu](https://github.com/msurguy/laravel-shop-menu)

It hasn't had a commit in over a year, but combining it with the AJAX shopping cart on tutorialzine.com might help.